# Strange behaviour of numpy eigenvector: bug or no bug

Tags: numpy, eigenvector

NumPy's eigenvector solution differs from Wolfram Alpha and my personal calculation by hand.

```py
>>> import numpy.linalg
>>> import numpy as np
>>> numpy.linalg.eig(np.array([[-2, 1], [2, -1]]))
(array([-3.,  0.]), array([[-0.70710678, -0.4472136 ],
       [ 0.70710678, -0.89442719]]))
```

Wolfram Alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+%7B%7B-2,1%7D,%7B%2B2,-1%7D%7D and my personal calculation give the eigenvectors (-1, 1) and (2, 1). The NumPy solution however differs.

NumPy's calculated eigenvalues however are confirmed by Wolfram Alpha and my personal calculation.

So, is this a bug in NumPy or is my understanding of math to simple? A similar thread [Numpy seems to produce incorrect eigenvectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589448/numpy-seems-to-produce-incorrect-eigenvectors) sees the main difference in rounding/scaling of the eigenvectors but the deviation between the solutions would be massive.

Regards

Comment: The rank of you input array is one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.linalg.eig` normalizes the eigen vectors with the results being the column vectors

```
eig_vectors = np.linalg.eig(np.array([[-2, 1], [2, -1]]))[1]
vec_1 = eig_vectors[:,0]
vec_2 = eig_vectors[:,1]
```

now these 2 vectors are just normalized versions of the vectors you calculated ie

```
print(vec_1 * np.sqrt(2)) # where root 2 is the magnitude of [-1, 1]
print(vec_1 * np.sqrt(5)) # where root 5 is the magnitude of [2, 1]
```

So bottom line the both sets of calculations are equivalent just Numpy likes to normalze the results.