# Why does my Numpy code return incorrect eigenvector values?

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

The problem I am having is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589448/numpy-seems-to-produce-incorrect-eigenvectors).

However, I believe the answer to the above question does not apply to my case.

```
    matrix = np.array([[10,3,1],[3,2,1],[1,1,1]])
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors =np.linalg.eigh(matrix) # using eigh because matrix is symmetric matrix
    print([np.dot((matrix@eigenvectors[i])/np.linalg.norm(matrix@eigenvectors[i]),eigenvectors[i]/np.linalg.norm(eigenvectors[i])) for i in range(matrix.shape[0])])
```

If I am correct, the above code should return 1, equal to the size of the matrix. Of course, I am assuming that it will not be exactly 1 because of errors, but it should still be close to 1.

However, the above code returns the following values:

```
    [0.7721913042777805, 0.5341128829187937, 0.9019035049538643]
```

Isn't this answer too bad?

By the way, if we calculate the eigenvectors of this matrix in wolfram alpha, I got:

```
[[ 0.12586458 -0.32039088 -0.93888646]]
 [-0.65562141 0.68341326 -0.32110261]
 [ [ 0.74452581 0.65596951 -0.1240376 ]]
```

Substituting this into eigenvectors and executing the following code in the same way,

```
    print([np.dot((matrix@eigenvectors[i])/np.linalg.norm(matrix@eigenvectors[i]),eigenvectors[i]/np.linalg.norm(eigenvectors[i])) for i in range(matrix.shape[0])])
```

The following result is obtained:

```
    [0.9999999999999705, 0.9999999999834726, 0.9999999999737305]
```

Comment: are you testing rows or columns of the eigenvectors array?  Reread the docs

Comment: @hpaulj is correct, trying `eigenvectors[:,i]` gives `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`

Comment: Note that the answer to the question you quoted contains also your answer. Specifically the fact that eiden vectors are the columns of the `eigenvectors` matrix returned by `eigh`

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is correctly calculating the eigenvectors, you can verify it by displaying them with a print statement. The issue is that you are taking the eigenvectors incorrectly. When using eigh, make sure to take the columns of the eigenvector matrix and not the rows as you are currently doing.

Here´s the solution:

```
print([np.dot(matrix @ eigenvectors[:, i] / np.linalg.norm(matrix @ eigenvectors[:, i]), eigenvectors[:, i]) for i in range(matrix.shape[0])])
```

Doing that little modification i got the expected result:

```
[0.9999999999999998, 0.9999999999999996, 0.9999999999999996]
```

Let me know if it works :)