# scipy.linalg.eig eigenvectors don't match those obtained by other programming languages

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

Kf=np.array([[1.26336E+05,0.00000E+00,-6.31680E+04,1.57920E+06,0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00],
            [0.00000E+00,1.05280E+08,-1.57920E+06,2.63200E+07,0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00],
            [-6.31680E+04,-1.57920E+06,1.26336E+05,0.00000E+00,-6.31680E+04,1.57920E+06],
            [1.57920E+06,2.63200E+07,0.00000E+00,1.05280E+08,-1.57920E+06,2.63200E+07],
            [0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00,-6.31680E+04,-1.57920E+06,1.26336E+05,0.00000E+00],
            [0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00,1.57920E+06,2.63200E+07,0.00000E+00,1.05280E+08]])

Mf=np.array([[3.71429E+00,0.00000E+00,6.42857E-01,-7.73810E+00,0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00],
            [0.00000E+00,2.38095E+02,7.73810E+00,-8.92857E+01,0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00],
            [6.42857E-01,7.73810E+00,3.71429E+00,0.00000E+00,6.42857E-01,-7.73810E+00],
            [-7.73810E+00,-8.92857E+01,0.00000E+00,2.38095E+02,7.73810E+00,-8.92857E+01],
            [0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00,6.42857E-01,7.73810E+00,3.71429E+00,0.00000E+00],
            [0.00000E+00,0.00000E+00,-7.73810E+00,-8.92857E+01,0.00000E+00,2.38095E+02]])

print(linalg.eig(Kf,Mf)[1])
```

The first eigenvector is as follows:

```
6.58724479e-01 -1.99225436e-01  6.87078346e-01  5.71471739e-01   7.06790814e-01  4.30845944e-01
```

On normalising the eigenvector with respect to the maximum value, we get:

```
1.000E+00   2.561E-01   -1.029E-15  4.164E-01   -1.000E+00  2.561E-01
```

However, on solving the same problem using GNU Octave or Julia, I get the normalised first eigenvector as:

```
5.435E-01   1.522E-02   1.000E+00   -1.152E-17  5.435E-01   -1.522E-02
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy seems to produce incorrect eigenvectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589448/numpy-seems-to-produce-incorrect-eigenvectors)

Comment: Notice that you're taking the rows of the matrix returned by SciPy when the columns contain the eigenvectors (read the documentation to see this). The other issues mentioned in the post I share as duplicate may also be present (i.e. rotated eigenvectors if they are not unique and not checking that you're comparing eigenvectors of the same eigenvalues).

Comment: Apologies for the mistake. You're right, Scipy does provide the eigenvectors in columns. Also, I missed the fact that the order of the eigenvalues in Scipy is opposite to that calculated by Octave.

Comment: If the post I suggested as duplicate answers your question then you can use that to close this question as duplicate.